# Actual implementation of Callable and Future

Tags: java, concurrency, theory, future, callable

I am in the process of understanding fine grain util.concurrency.  Where is implementation of the Java `Callable` and `Future` located in the JVM ?

I have found the [Future class](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/Future.java) where it describes the future on the high level in Java lang, I am trying to find where it is described on the lower level.

To sum up it would be interesting to find the actual implementation of Future and Callable e.g: the part of the JVM that handles the Future.get() or Callable.call() and prescribes them how they should work.

Looking forward for your replies,
Akonkagva

Comment: So, they dont include any black magic that is done by the JVM ?

Comment: @Gray thank you for your answer, so it is the Thread class that enchances the functionality of the Callable ?

Comment: You usually get a `Future` if you pass a (self-implemented) `Callable` to an `ExecutorService`. There are several executor service implementations in the JDK where you can look how they handle it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Where is implementation of the Java Callable and Future located in the JVM ?

The main implementation of the `Future` interface is the [`FutureTask` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html).  It is used by the `ExecutorService` classes to represent a submitted job, etc..  `Callable` (like `Runnable`) is a simple interface that you implement yourself.  It wraps a task that you want the `ExecutorService` thread-pools to execute.  You should download the source jars for these classes and take a look at the Java code yourself.

Neither of these classes contain any JVM black magic or anything.  For example, if you construct a `Callable` class, it won't run in another thread unless you submit it to a thread-pool.  You can use the `Callable` in many different places that have nothing to do with threads.

The JVM "black magic" around `Future` and `Callable` is mostly contained in the `Thread` class.  It has underlying native support which works with the OS threads to do the actual job of running your task in another thread.  There is still a lot of Java code in it if you want to see what it does but there are native and OS calls that the real magic.

Here's a [good tutorial about how to use the executor services](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html) that were added to Java in 1.5.

Comment: No.  A `Future` is just a job wrapper.  If you have a thread-pool with 10 threads, you might submit 100k `Future` jobs to that thread-pool @raffian.

Answer (score 4):

The [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/) library has its own implementation of `Future`: [`AbstractFuture`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AbstractFuture.java) (and subclasses like [`SettableFuture`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/SettableFuture.java)) which is an alternative to `FutureTask`.

If you are interested in learning how such things are implemented, this might also be interesting to look at. Usually the Guava code is very well written.

Answer (score 3):

`Future` is an interface. It has no implementation in itself, it just specify method signatures. You can check source of any of class that implements this interface. Some public classes bundled with JVM are:

- [FutureTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html)
- [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)

You can use grepcode to see their implementation.

Comment: This is confusing.  Most interfaces have implementations and `FutureTask` is one such example.

Comment: @Gray What is confusing? `FutureTask` is only one example. Other implementation may do it in different way and have different logic. E.g. standard JVM library misses future implemenation where you can set value like here: [SettableFuture](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v13.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/SettableFuture.html)

Comment: Saying that the `Future` interface does not have an implementation is confusing.  In the same package there is an implementation which is used by the concurrent classes.  Maybe you want to reword?

Comment: @Gray ah, yes, it's confusing. Thank you